# C# image save dots

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, filestream, exif

I don't know that i'm doing wrong, I have been looking around the web, and tried a lot of different things but nothing works, when i try to save the image there is a lot of gray dots

the result can be seen here 
http://postimg.org/image/btvob8f6l/

```
    public static void ExifSave(List<InfoList> data)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 50L);
        myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 100L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;

        list = data;
        foreach (InfoList i in data)
        {
            SetProperty(ref prop, i.id, i.value);
            image.SetPropertyItem(prop);
        }
        fs.Dispose();
        try
        {
            image.Save(Path);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            new MessagePromt("DEBUG::LoadImages()::Error attempting to create image::" + e.Message, e.Message);
        }
    }
    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
        foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
        {
            if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
            {
                return codec;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Test with much smaller image and see what `data` contains.

Comment: What is the type of the image object?

Comment: system.drawing.bitmap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `image` is a `Bitmap` class, you may need to pass the `EncoderParameters` into the `Save` method

```
image.Save(Path, jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

Comment: tried that it gives the same result, have also tried to use bitmap instead of image